# Windows 2000 VS IIS7.5 windows 2012 compability Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, iis, iis-7.5

I have an application that works under windows server 2000 I have no idea what version of IIS it is using but it seens to be so old .

I have ben asked to make it functional under IIS7.5 with a 2012 windows server

problem is the code of the application is too old too

Here is an exemple

```
function validate(){
            strFile = document.ValidForm.Search.value

            if (strFile.length < 3) {
                alert("You must type a value with at least 3 characters.");
                document.ValidForm.Search.focus()
                document.ValidForm.Search.select()}
            else    {
                document.search_dg.action = "SomePerlFile.plx";
                document.search_dg.Search.value = strFile;
                document.search_dg.method = "post";
                document.search_dgtarget = "results";
                //document.search_dg.onsubmit = window.open('', 'winReq', 'toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=500');
                document.search_dgn.submit();
                //document.search_dgn.target = "_self";
            }
        }
```

that part of code is generating error under chrome and firefox . I assume because it's old

Once I run the page , in the chrome debugger I receive an error on this line

```
strFile = document.ValidForm.Search.value
```

Chrome claims that `(index):15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Search' of undefined`

but the Search box is defined inside the document

```
<TABLE height="59" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <FORM ID="ValidForm" ACTION="" METHOD="POST" target="results" NAME="search_dgn" onSubmit="validate(); return false;">
                        <TR>
<TD width="176">
                                <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Search" MAXLENGTH="100" style="width:100%">
                            </TD>
```

so My big question is that is there any way I can configure my IIS7.5 in a way to handle codes and stuff that used to exist in the 2000 ?

I'm trying to avoid changing code at most cost ( I'm pretty sure If I write document.getelementbyId it should work....)

But the thing I'm aiming at , is to make ISS format or handle ...old generation code

Any sort of help and comment is highly appreciated

Comment: 1. JavaScript is executed on the client. 2. "_generating error under chrome and firefox_" - and what error?

Comment: @Andreas let's say I have server sided error and client side error. On the client side in the chrome debugger I'm receiving : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Search' of undefined...... I assume he is not regonising this : strFile = document.ValidForm.Search.value....... but this Search box is well defined <TD width="176">
         <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Search" MAXLENGTH="100" style="width:100%">
        </TD>

Comment: Please add this to the question itself and not only as a comment as this is an important information - including the markup of the form.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for your notice , I updated the question with more important information that help the community understand the problem !

Comment: `name` attribute of most elements is obsoleted. Use `id`s and `getElementById` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of what @Teemu said:

Add an id attribute to the `input` field:

```
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="Search" NAME="Search" MAXLENGTH="100" style="width:100%">
```

then use

```
var strFile = document.getElementById('Search').value;
```

at the top of the function to get your element.

This shouldn't have anything to do with IIS.